# Using COM objects from Java applets

Tags: com, applet

I want to implement a  Java applet to wrap specific COM object to use it's functionality in browsers other than IE. Can this be done or some applet security permissions will prohibit that?

Answer (score 0):

If an applet can load COM objects, it would have to be digitally signed and trusted by the end user.  To put that another way, a typical sand-boxed applet would not be able to load them.